# how to save data from this partial view into Vehicle_driver Table?? using Entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have 2 controllers (DRIVER Controller and VEHICLE controller) i need to map vehicle with a driver. i have created a partial view where in one can select a vehicle to a particular driver.

Now how to save data from this partial view into Vehicle_driver Table??

Vehicle_driver has these fields

```
VEHICLE_ID       bigint(20) PK    
DRIVER_ID        varchar(36) PK    
SERVICE_START_DATE datetime PK    
SERVICE_END_DATE datetime
```

---

Vehicle Table has fields like

```
ID               bigint(20) PK    
REG_NO           varchar(50)    
VEHICLE_TYPE     int(11)    
SERVICE_START_DATE datetime    
SERVICE_EXPIRE_DATE datetime    
OWNER_ID         varchar(36)
```

and Driver table has fields called

---

```
ID               varchar(36) PK    
LICENCE_NO       varchar(50)    
FIRST_NAME       varchar(50)    
LAST_NAME        varchar(50)    
ADDRESS          varchar(1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Vehicle_driver Assign(Driver d, Vehicle v, DateTime start, DateTime end) {
  using (MyContext context = new MyContext()) {
    Vehicle_driver assignment = context.CreateObject<Vehicle_driver>();
    assignment.VEHICLE_ID = v.ID;
    assignment.DRIVER_ID = d.ID;
    assignment.SERVICE_START_DATE = start;
    assignment.SERVICE_END_DATE = end;
    context.Vehicle_drivers.AddObject(assignment);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return assignment;
  }
}
```

Comment: Np, if it's a satisfactory answer, please don't forget to mark it as such.